# How to use the web service client generetad by eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm using Eclipse Juno to create a Web Service Client for consuming a WSDL SOAP web service.

It generated 2 packages, one with the web service name and another with "org.tempuri.dataset_ISI_xsd".

Inside the first package there are some classes like:

1- ServiceName

2- ServiceNameProxy

3- ServiceNameService

4- ServiceNameServiceLocator

5- ServiceNameSoapBindingStub

**I'd like to know wich class should I use to call the web service methods and how to obtain the values returned by the method.**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instantiate the xxxProxy class, call the setEndpoint() method passing the url of the web service host, then call the method matching the name of the web service.  The return type of the method will depend on the definition of the web service.

Comment: I call the method getRoutes() and it returns a GetRoutesResponseGetRoutesResult object, which is from a classe generated by eclipse. However, that class has no intuitive method to obtain the values I expect.

It's supposed to call any conversion method to convert the returned data to the ones generated in by eclipse? For instance, there is a DatasetISIRoute class that appereantly has the structure I expect but I don't know how to obtain it from the GetRoutesResponseGetRoutesResult object returned by the service.

Comment: Refer to the wsdl file to see how the GetRoutesResponseGetRoutesResult is defined.